# Custom fonts dosen't work with react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Trying to integrate custom fonts 'Tajawal-Bold' and 'Tajawal-Medium' with my RN project that use react-native-paper. (Android app only)
I did like described in the documentation of react-native=paper, https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/fonts.html.

This fonts are applied to RN components, but paper component  doesn't.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Make sure your font files are .ttf files. Once done, restart your project to refresh changes. If still not working share screenshots of fonts folder and command you fired on cmd with message

Comment: @NikhilParmar i did what say without success, and my files (.ttf) are in forlder named assets/fonts.  
and this is the content of react-native.config.js
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {}, 
    },
    assets: ["./assets/fonts"], 
  };

Comment: Try to create a snack (https://snack.expo.io/) and share it here.

Comment: Also, make sure you have applied changes in this file. https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/styles/fonts.tsx

Comment: Did you run "react-native link"?

Comment: @raxerz, yes sure, the custom font is applied to RN elements like 'Text', but paper elements no

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixied this problem by eliminate using configureFonts function