# React-Native-Paper Theme won't use Custom Fonts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts, react-native-paper

I am working on a RN app using `react-native-paper` to handle theming and UI. I have the theme working to format my components, however when I try to incorporate custom fonts it does not have any effect on the `react-native-paper` components. I have followed the `[font guide][1]` but it did not change this issue.

I follow the expo example of how to load fonts using `loadFontAsync()`, and when I pass these fonts to my own components using the style prop `fontFamily: 'Rubik-Regular` the font works so I know it is not an issue of the font not existing.

As I am new to `react-native-paper`, I think my issue is with my `fontConfig` or `configureFonts()`. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './store'
]import { configureFonts, DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper'
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppNavigator from './components/AppNavigator'

const store = configureStore();

const fontConfig = {
    default: {
        regular: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Regular',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        medium: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Black',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        light: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Light',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        thin: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-LightItalic',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
    },
};

let customFonts = {
    'Rubik-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf'),
    'Rubik-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Rubik-Black.ttf'),
    'Rubik-Light': require('./assets/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf'),
    'Rubik-LightItalic': require('./assets/fonts/Rubik-LightItalic.ttf'),
}


const theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    roundness: 30,
    fonts: configureFonts(fontConfig),
    colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: '#0d80d6',
        accent: '#E68FAE',
        background: '#C6E1F2',
    },
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fontsLoaded: false,
        };
    }

    async loadFontsAsync() {
        await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
        this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadFontsAsync();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.fontsLoaded) {
         return (
                <ReduxProvider store={store}>
                    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
                        <AppNavigator/>
                    </PaperProvider>
                </ReduxProvider>
            );
        }
        else {
            return <AppLoading/>;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `react-native 0.63.3` and `Expo`.

Comment: I have looked at this post on [Loading custom fonts in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558915/load-customised-font-in-react-native) as well as this one on [fonts not working in react-native-paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008481/custom-fonts-dosent-work-with-react-native-paper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is from a while ago but I ran into the same problem today and found this related issue in their repository on GitHub: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1502#issuecomment-576534682

TL;DR the solution is you have to specify `fontConfig.ios` and probably `fontConfig.android` for it to work, instead of just having `fontConfig.default`.

for your case, you can probably adapt to something like

```js
const _fontConfig = {
        regular: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Regular',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        medium: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Black',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        light: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-Light',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
        thin: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik-LightItalic',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
        },
};

const fontConfig = {
    ios: _fontConfig,
    android: _fontConfig,
};
```